# Not able share the static content and URl to twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

Here i want to share the `static content` and 'URL' to twitter , i am trying but i am not able share the both,kindly check my code ,what i did wrong,if anyone know means please my update the code,

Suppose i am sharing separately means it is working fine.separate means i am sharing only static content means working fine , suppose i am sharing one url means working,when ever i am trying both that not working

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
$static_content = "This photo is awesome! Check it out below link";
$url = "http://g2evolution.in/spreadit_API/event-details.php?id=MQ==&postedCustonerId=MQ==&eventType=UHVibGlj";
?>

<br><br>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status=<?php echo $static_content?>">Content Sharing</a><br><br>


<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo $url?>">Link Sharing</a> <br></br>

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?status=<?php echo $static_content.'&url='.$url ?>">Share Both on Twitter</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because they are adding to url, you may need pass the values through `urlencode` before pushing into HTML.

Comment: Can you please update your code